# Adding to UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am working on an iPhone app, but i need to be able to add things to a UITableView...
What is the easiest way to do this?

Techy

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a UITableViewController which is backed by an NSMutableArray (or NSArray), then the first thing you have to do is add the new object to your array with something like:

```
[objects addObject:obj];
```

Then call

```
[tableView reload]
```

which will cause `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` to be checked.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [objects count]; 
}
```

Finally, `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will be invoked, which you have probably already written to handle rendering cells.